# How to get query result from another channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a trouble when I want to get query result in my fabric. I have 2 channels, channel 1 stored account data, channel 2 stored some content and their cost. I am in channel 1,I want to query a content's cost in channel2,then "buy" it in channel 1. For example,channel1 have an account A and he has $20,channel2 have a movie cost $9, A wants to query the cost of the movie, then "buy" it, so A only have $11 now. But now I don't know how to get the "$9" from channel2. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric uses channels as a form of isolation.
How ever you can invoke another chaincode using 'InvokeChaincode' API.

```
// InvokeChaincode locally calls the specified chaincode `Invoke` using the
    // same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't
    // create a new transaction message.
    // If the called chaincode is on the same channel, it simply adds the called
    // chaincode read set and write set to the calling transaction.
    // If the called chaincode is on a different channel,
    // only the Response is returned to the calling chaincode; any PutState calls
    // from the called chaincode will not have any effect on the ledger; that is,
    // the called chaincode on a different channel will not have its read set
    // and write set applied to the transaction. Only the calling chaincode's
    // read set and write set will be applied to the transaction. Effectively
    // the called chaincode on a different channel is a `Query`, which does not
    // participate in state validation checks in subsequent commit phase.
    // If `channel` is empty, the caller's channel is assumed.
    InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName string, args [][]byte, channel string) pb.Response
```

[Source](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L76)

Comment: Thank you very much! I find that the function return value of the API is a "pb.response", so I think maybe I can get the query result from the "pb.response". Is it right?